# python: print time & date with timezone information

Tags: python, django, time

I have a piece of code using `django` library to print a date/time with timezone in the following way:

```
2019-11-04 22:25:00.831219+00:00
```

I would like to get rid of `django`, since in this script it's only used to print date/time+timezone. How can I do this using standard `python` library?

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(d)
```

This gives the output as this:

```
2019-11-04 19:05:07.176493
```

So how do I specify timezone information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the [`tz` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) with a `tzinfo`, e.g:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

d = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
2019-11-04 22:48:09.666543+00:00
```